# Qt3d: Light attenuation is not applied to QText2DEntity

Tags: c++, qt, qt3d

So far, I used the light attenuation (the linearAttenuation and quadraticAttenuation properties of the QPointLight class) in order to obtain a fog effect. This way, the further an entity is from the light entity, the foggier it gets.

The problem is that the light attenuation is not applied to QText2DEntity.

Is there a way to fix this?
Also, if this is not the best way to obtain the fog effect, can you suggest a different approach?